# How to disable multi select dropdown in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used **angular2 dropdown multi-select** using below code

```
 <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" name="pack" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="model.selectedPackValue"  [disabled]="canViewData">
```

But I can not able to disable this dropdown when my **'canViewData'** **is true**

Then how to disable it ?

Comment: It should work fine. Check your `canViewData` once.

Comment: best way to set true value static and if it work replace with variable

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution as including below code in my **multiselectdropdown.ts**

At 117 line add
      **@Input() disable: string;**

and also add attribute to button at 76 line **[disabled]="disable"**

Now the below code in my template works fine..

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" name="pack" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="model.selectedPackValue"  [disable]="canViewData">
```

(and also above all changes are applied to multiselectdropdown.js)

Answer (score 1):

Your are using some plugin

I think this is the one
https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Go to your node_modules folder from your solution and find the file 'multiselect-dropdown.ts'

https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/src/multiselect-dropdown.ts

At 117 line
add

```
@Input() disable: boolean;
```

At 76
add attribute to button

```
[disabled]="disable"
```

Now try the below code in your template this may help

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" name="pack" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="model.selectedPackValue"  [disable]="canViewData">
```

Comment: And what do you do if they update the multiselect ? You do that again ?

Comment: If i need urgent solution,I do like this, . May be i am wrong. But reporting to github and waiting for update may takes time? If you have any proper way ,kindly comment.

Comment: Here in @Input() disable: boolean; have not worked for me because it gave me error as BOOLEAN is not defined so instead of BOOLEAN i have used STRING then everything works fine. Thank you.